# mySQL query creating empty columns

Tags: mysql, html

I am trying to capture data from my form and pump it into a database, but when I try to input data into a column, I only get the uid, and the rest of the columns are empty.

Here is some code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO personal_information (uid, name, surname, email, cell) 
VALUES ('".$uid."', '".$name."', '".$surname."', '".$email."', '".$cell."' )")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO consumer_related_info (uid) 
VALUES ('".$uid."')")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO family_scenario (uid) 
VALUES ('".$uid."')")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO lifestyle_activities (uid) 
VALUES ('".$uid."')")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO occupational_information (uid) 
VALUES ('".$uid."')")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO sport_activities (uid) 
VALUES ('".$uid."')")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vehicle_details (uid) 
VALUES ('".$uid."')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Do all the variables that you are using definitely contain values? What is the result if you echo their contents immediately prior to building your SQL statement?  Does the `INSERT` statement produce an error? Also, you would be much better off using [prepared statements](http://uk3.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), either through [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or directly with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: whats the value of `register_globals` (see php.ini or `phpinfo()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sending the data with php?
then read http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php
and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

**Edit**
With the given information its more guessing then debugging. But i would bet that `register_globals` is the problem here.

What to do? Simple use `superglobals`.

```
// assumed the form method is post
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']));
// and so on
```

If this does not help: fill your form with dummy-values, dump your request-data (and post it here)

```
echo '<pre>'
     . print_r($_REQUEST, true)
     . '</pre>';
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated tip: make sure that the variables you're interpolating are escaped using `addslashes` to protect against the majority of injection attacks.

Actually... that could be quite related. Quotes and other unescaped characters could lead to the "breaking-out" of the string and cause a MySQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if your variables has a value assigned and what it is

```
$values = array( $uid, $name, $surname, $email, $cell );
print_r( $values );
```

Check the output.

After that is said. I would execute my queries like this

```
$query = sprintf( "INSERT INTO personal_information (uid,name,surname,email,cell) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string($uid),
mysql_real_escape_string($name),
mysql_real_escape_string($surname),
mysql_real_escape_string($email),
mysql_real_escape_string($cell));

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

By escaping all the input, you are secure against mysql_injections (i dont know if you are totally secure). This is very important!! I don't know how familiar you are with mysql injections, but with your setup it would be easy for a hacker to view your entire database!! And i am sure you don't want that to happen :) Am i right?

Have a nice day!!

Comment: I am getting all of the data from the form, but for some reason it wont go into the DB, it just shows blank columns!

Comment: Can you post a sample of post values? Have you tried to escape the inputs?